# Display only needed decimals from double

Tags: delphi

I want to convert a double to a string and only display needed decimals.

So I cannot use

```
d := 123.4
s := Format('%.2f', [d]);
```

As it display as the result is 123.40 when I want 123.4.

Here is a table of samples and expected result

```
|Double|Result as string|
-------------------------
|5     |5               |
|5.1   |5.1             |
|5.12  |5.12            |
|5.123 |5.123           |
```

Comment: You want to strip the zeroes, if present at the end of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `%g` [format string](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format):

> **General**: The argument must be a floating-point value. The value is converted to the shortest possible decimal string using fixed or
>   scientific format. The number of significant digits in the resulting
>   string is given by the precision specifier in the format string; a
>   default precision of 15 is assumed if no precision specifier is
>   present. Trailing zeros are removed from the resulting string, and a
>   decimal point appears only if necessary. The resulting string uses the
>   fixed-point format if the number of digits to the left of the decimal
>   point in the value is less than or equal to the specified precision,
>   and if the value is greater than or equal to 0.00001. Otherwise the
>   resulting string uses scientific format.

Comment: Try this with `const d: Double = 0.1000000000000001;`

Answer (score 2):

This is not as simple as you think. It all boils down to representability.

Let's consider a simple example of `0.1`. That value is not exactly representable in `double`. This is because `double` is a **binary** representation rather than a **decimal** representation.

A `double` value is stored in the form `s*2^e`, where `s` and `e` are the significand and exponent respectively, both integers.

Back to `0.1`. That value cannot be exactly represented as a binary floating point value. No combination of significand and exponent exist that represent it. Instead the [closest representable value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.1) will be used:

```
0.10000 00000 00000 00555 11151 23125 78270 21181 58340 45410 15625
```

If this comes as a shock I suggest the following references:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
- http://floating-point-gui.de/

So, what to do? An obvious option is to switch to a decimal rather than binary representation. In Delphi that typically means using the `Currency` type. Depending on your application that might be a good choice, or it might be a terrible choice. If you wish to perform scientific or engineering calculations efficiently, for instance, then a decimal type is not appropriate.

Another option would be to look at how Python handles this. The `repr` function is meant, where possible, to yield a string with the property that `eval(repr(x)) == x`. In older versions of Python `repr` produced very long strings of the form `1.1000000000000001` when in fact `1.1` would suffice. Python [adopted an algorithm](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580) that finds the shortest decimal expression that represents the floating point value. You could adopt the same approach. The snag is that the algorithm is very complex.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this problem. But in my case %g works fine.

Comment: Not always it won't. Not for all possible values.